# Express and PassportJs - Google OAuth2.0 strategy not giving me a req.user object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, passport.js

I'm setting up an auth route for our application, and I cannot seem to get the Google oAuth 2.0 strategy for PassportJs to give me a req.user object, using sequelize. Below is my code, I have tried to snip out only the relevant parts :)

**Here's how my app.js is set up:**

```
//Dependencies
const creds = require('./credentials');
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const SequelizeStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(session.Store);
const sequelize = new Sequelize(creds.mssqlAuth);

//Routes
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth');

//Init
const app = express

//View engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

//Session config
app.use(session({
  secret: 'this is a super secret session sign in string',
  store:  new SequelizeStore({
    db: sequelize,
    checkExpirationInterval: 15 * 60 * 1000,
    expiration: 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  }),
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000, secure : true }
}));

//Init middlewares
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Init Routes
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/auth', authRouter);
```

**Here's my auth route:**

```
'use strict';

// Dependencies
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const creds = require('../credentials');
const Models = require('../models');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(creds.mssqlAuth);

//Init router
const router = express.Router();

//Winston logging - dev purposes only
const winston = require('winston');

//Authenticate with Google and get users data
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: creds.googleAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret: creds.googleAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/callback'
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    Models.users.findOne({
      where: {
        email: profile.emails[0].value,
      }
    }).then( user =>{
      if (user){

        Models.user.update({
          **Update existing user here...**
          },
          where: { **Update existing user here...**} })

        .then( user =>{

          return Models.users.findOne({
            where: { email: profile.emails[0].value }
          });

        }).then(user =>{
          return done(null, user);

        }).catch(error => { return done(error, null)});
      }
      else if(!user){
        //****For the sake of brevity - Same as above, only create the new user****//
      }

    }).catch(error => { return done(error, null)});

//Serialization
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  Models.users.findOne({
    where: { id: id }
  })
    .then(user => done(null, user))
    .catch(error => done(error, null));
});

//Initial auth call to Google
router.get('/',
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    hd: 'ourDomain.com',
    scope: ['email'],
    prompt: 'select_account'
  })
);

//Callback - Send user to index or back to auth screen
router.get('/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', 
    { failureRedirect: '/auth',
      successRedirect: '/' }
));
```

I seem to be able to authenticate all of that, and I even get a new user written to our users table. But then in my index route I am checking to make sure req.user exists. It is always undefined, and this results in a loop back to the auth route.

I'm wondering if it has something to do with setting this up under //localhost instead of an actual server? This code is intended to be a boilerplate setup for us to quickly get underway on new projects.

Curiously, this code seems to write 3 separate sessions to our sessions table as well, each time it's run. I'm unsure if that's an unrelated issue, or if it's the cause of our issues here.

Does anyone have some guidance?

Comment: We did end up finding a solution to this, and It was related to running the app on localhost. I will type up an answer shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this was rather simple - I was setting our session cookie as secure

Here is the relevant documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#cookiesecure

All that was needed was to change the app.js code from this:

```
//Session config
app.use(session({
  secret: 'this is a super secret session sign in string',
  store:  new SequelizeStore({
    db: sequelize,
    checkExpirationInterval: 15 * 60 * 1000,
    expiration: 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  }),
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000, secure : true },
  secure: true
}));
```

To this:

```
//Session config
app.use(session({
  secret: 'this is a super secret session sign in string',
  store:  new SequelizeStore({
    db: sequelize,
    checkExpirationInterval: 15 * 60 * 1000,
    expiration: 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  }),
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }
}));

//****************************************//
//***** Note the lack of secure: true ****//
//****************************************//
```

The reason for this is due to the app running on http (since its localhost). With that setup, secure: true prevents a cookie from ever being sent to the deserialize function inside of the auth route. This makes the whole auth process fail. In production, obviously we will change our config, but this works good for now.

I hope this saves someone some time in the future, here's to one line fixes :)